# Dart difference between = and : in named parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class Student {
  String name;
  int age;
  int id;

  Student({this.name, this.id = 101, this.age: 20});
}
```

What is the difference between `=` and `:` in above constructor? Both seems to do the same job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Deprecation note: Old code might use a colon (:) instead of = to set
>   default values of named parameters. The reason is that originally,
>   only : was supported for named parameters. That support is likely to
>   be deprecated, so we recommend that you use = to specify default
>   values.

Source:
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour